# Why doesn't spring provide a thread scope implementation?

Tags: multithreading, spring, scope

Why doesn't Spring provide a thread scope implementation?
Has anyone used thread scoped beans with Spring in a web application context? 
There should be a standard, clear description of how to do this! 
(SpringByExample has a solution—I didn't test it—but it is not mainstream yet.)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Spring does provide a thread scope, but it is not registered by default.

The existing bean scopes are defined in the documentation, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes).

> **singleton**
>
> - (Default) Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring IoC container.
>
> **prototype**
>
> - Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object
>     instances.
>
> **request**
>
> - Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of
>     a single HTTP request; that is, each HTTP request has its own instance
>     of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition. Only valid
>     in the context of a web-aware Spring `ApplicationContext`.
>
> **session**
>
> - Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of an HTTP Session.
>     Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>     global
>
> **application**
>
> - Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a `ServletContext`. Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring
>     `ApplicationContext`.
>
> **websocket**
>
> - Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a `WebSocket`. Only
>     valid in the context of a web-aware Spring `ApplicationContext`.

The documentation then makes a note

> As of Spring 3.0, a thread scope is available, but is not registered
>   by default. For more information, see the documentation for
>   [`SimpleThreadScope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html).

Note that, similarly to the prototype scope, the thread scope

> [`SimpleThreadScope`] does not clean up any objects associated with it.

This thread scope implementation uses a `ThreadLocal` to store beans.
You cannot detect a `Thread` ending/dying in Java, so the Spring IOC container cannot explicitly know when to remove the beans from the `ThreadLocal` and invoke any end of lifecycle methods. That responsibility then falls on the developer.

Be careful where you use this scope. For example, in a thread pooling context, a bean might already have been created and stored in one of the pools' reused threads. Depending on your use case, that might be the incorrect behavior.

Comment: I didn't fully understand your answer, can you explain it further? You say we cannot detect a thread ending but why is it a problem? If the IOC container creates an instance and puts it to the ThreadLocal storage of that thread, then it can hand it off to the thread and whenever that thread dies, the objects on the thread local storage will be garbage collected, isn't it right? Then why DI container should care about the lifecycle of the thread, it can just inject the object and hand it off. What am I missing here?

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir Spring can run code when a dependency is taken out of service by the container. For instance, a method could be annotated with [`@PreDestroy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html) for this purpose.  It "is typically used to release resources that it has been holding". Imagine a thread-scoped bean that acquires a connection to a database. When the bean is no longer needed, that connection should be closed, which could be done in @PreDestroy. Garbage collecting this bean won't cause the method to be called, so the connection will still be active.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it does provide a thread scope, since Spring 3.0. You might need to register it yourself instead of that it is used out-of-the-box.

See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-2581

Comment: If you are talking about org.springframework.context.support.SimpleThreadScope, this does not do any cleanup and it's unusable. It is basically a thread pool scope ..., which is werid! :) SpringByExample has an implementation which could be working, but I didn't try it yet.

Comment: For a tomcat app that is killed when a new version to be deployed, and the beans will then be made when app is created (assuming thread pools are only the ones made by tomcat to service web requests), then the beans would be like  service beans with the lifetime == app life time == till tomcat lives? so work well - not singletons or web session scope but still less clash if methods are thread safe within themselves

Answer (score 4):

In a web application context, you can use request scope that is roughly the same as using a thread scope. A request scoped bean is created for every request received by the server and discarded when the request is finished.

Consider that threads may be pooled on servers, and that's probably the reason why there is not a thread scope on Spring

Take a look at request scope: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: Your answer is for a different question :(. The request scope beans do not autowire for asynchronous serverside processing. If there is a need to have a batch job or any other background processing, you cannot use your spring beans because will fail at autowiring the request scoped beans.

Comment: You asked about using thread scoped beans in a Web application context, and that's exactly what I answered.

Comment: Well, thread scope is not quite the same as request scope, they are "roughly the same". Maybe I wasn't clear enough in the question. Thanks for the reply anyway!

Comment: Remember that threads may be pooled on servers, and that's probably the reason why there is not a thread scope on Spring.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that! This might be a reason, but a cleanup can be done on the thread state, in order to achieve the thread scope behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in accepted answer, [SimpleThreadScope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/SimpleThreadScope.html) is not doing objects cleanup on thread exit. However, Spring's documentation points to Spring by Example implementation, that takes care of it - check out [ThreadScope](https://www.springbyexample.org/maven/site/sbe-thread-scope/1.0.5/sbe-thread-scope/apidocs/org/springbyexample/bean/scope/thread/ThreadScope.html).

Example of this custom scope registration from Spring by Example [website](https://www.springbyexample.org/examples/custom-thread-scope-module.html):

```
<bean id="threadCounter" 
      class="org.springbyexample.bean.scope.thread.Counter" 
      scope="thread" />

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="thread">
                <bean class="org.springbyexample.bean.scope.thread.ThreadScope"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then you use it as:
`@Scope("thread")`

Important note - in order for destruction callbacks to run, you must wrap your [Runnable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) in [ThreadScopeRunnable](https://www.springbyexample.org/maven/site/sbe-thread-scope/1.0.5/sbe-thread-scope/apidocs/org/springbyexample/bean/scope/thread/ThreadScopeRunnable.html).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be another implementation: `org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.thread.ThreadScope`

It is contained in the spring-cloud-context jar.