# Thread safety in Mutable Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, apache-kafka, thread-safety

1. I have `Spring Boot` service which is a listener to `Kafka` cluster with `@KafkaListner`
2. `Kafka` provides `json` data to instruct my service on what need to do.
3. I convert this configuration `json` to `pojo` upon receiving it.
4. I want to **share** this `pojo` across my `classes` & `methods`.
5. I don't want to pass through intermediary classes which don't need to know it

So, I did it like this.

1. Create empty `pojo` and save into spring container first.
2. Then, after receiving from `Kafka`, fetch empty pojo from `spring container` and `set` its values
3. This way I can get it from anywhere in my service.

But, I find this mutable pojo is not thread-safe. I explored bean-scope and nothing seems to suit me.

1. How can I make it thread-safe? Please provide an example on using custom `SimpleThreadScope`
2. Can you suggest any design pattern which doesn't need to use `spring bean`?

Comment: Threadsaftey is hard to achieve without an extra controlling instance I guess.
Thought about some pool with beans controlled by a flyweight factory like class with rejecting any use of a bean when its used atm?

Comment: Thread scope will not make it thread safe - it will give each thread its own copy. There's nothing major in Spring in regards to thread safety compared to just Java.

Comment: how about SimpleThreadScope? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552362/why-doesnt-spring-provide-a-thread-scope-implementation. Does it make it thread-safe?

Comment: As I already said - no, it will not. It will give each thread its own instance of the bean.

Comment: What do you mean by "Create empty pojo and save into spring container first.?"

Comment: i mean putting empty object into spring container with @Configuration